# How to stop loop from executing again after it has already finished iterating?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a calculator, and I used objects to store both the operator and the numbers put into the calculator. And then the loop in the evaluateOperation function takes the operator in the object along with the first value 'result' value and the second value and operates these values using the operate function.

The issue is, as soon as the loop is complete and exits, it loops again before exiting finally. Details can be found below, detailed comments on each part of the code.

```js
const number_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const input = document.getElementById('calc_display');
const op = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');

const multiplication = document.querySelector('#multiply');
const division = document.querySelector('#divide');
const addition = document.querySelector('#add');
const subtraction = document.querySelector('#subtract');

const evaluate = document.querySelector('#evaluate');
const decimal = document.querySelector('#decimal button');
const clearAllData = document.querySelector('.clear button')

//number storage
let num_display = {
  result: 0,
};

let operatorStorage = {};

let count = 0;
let operatorSequence = 0;
let iterable_for_post_result = 1;
let iterable_for_result = 0;
let operatorType;
let operationResult = 0;
let clicked = 1;
let decimalClicks = 0;

let called = 1;
//performs operation

function operate(operator, num1, num2) {
  switch (operator) {
    case '+':
      console.log(Number((add(num1, num2)).toFixed(2)));
      return Number((add(num1, num2)).toFixed(2));
      break;
    case '-':
      console.log(Number((subtract(num1, num2)).toFixed(2)));
      return Number((subtract(num1, num2)).toFixed(2));
      break;
    case '*':
      console.log(Number((multiply(num1, num2)).toFixed(2)));
      return Number((multiply(num1, num2)).toFixed(2));
      break;
    case '/':
      console.log(Number((divide(num1, num2)).toFixed(2)));
      return Number((divide(num1, num2)).toFixed(2));
      break;
  }
}

// When numbers are clicked eventlistener

number_buttons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (el.textContent == '.') {
      console.log('deci');
      if (decimalClicks == 1) {
        el.disabled = true;
        decimalClicks--;
      } else {
        decimalClicks++;
        el.disabled = false;
        input.value += el.textContent;
        if (count == 0) {
          // When an operation is called before a number is entered result becomes 0.
          num_display.result = Number(input.value);
        } else if (count >= 1) {
          num_display[`post_op_result ${count}`] = Number(input.value);
        }
      }
    } else {
      input.value += el.textContent;
      if (count == 0) {
        num_display.result = Number(input.value);
      } else if (count >= 1) {
        num_display[`post_op_result ${count}`] = Number(input.value);
      }
      console.log(num_display);
    }
  });
});

// Eventlistener when the '=' is clicked
// 

evaluate.addEventListener('click', () => {
  iterable_for_result;
  iterable_for_post_result;
  // Condition for if user does not click an operator
  if (operatorType == undefined || isNaN(operatorType) == true && Object.keys(num_display).length == 1) {
    return;
  } else {
    // Condition for if user does not input the first number
    if (input.value == '') {
      // if a user inputted the first number but did not enter an operator
      if (operatorType == undefined || isNaN(operatorType) == true) {
        operatorType = '+';
      }
      input.value = `${num_display['result']}`;
      operationResult = Number(input.value);
      console.log(operationResult);
      return operationResult;
    } else {
      let errorMessage = evaluateOperation(iterable_for_result, iterable_for_post_result);
      // if divide number by 0
      if (errorMessage == Infinity) {
        console.log('Bwana');
        errorMessage = 'YERRRRR';
        input.value = `${errorMessage}`;
        errorMessage = 0;
        operationResult = Number(input.value);
        num_display['result'] = operationResult;
      } else {

        //If no problems with inputs, calculates and calls evaluateOperation function

        input.value = `${evaluateOperation(iterable_for_result, iterable_for_post_result)}`;
        //operationResult = Number(input.value);
        //num_display['result'] = operationResult;
      }
    }
  }
  iterable_for_post_result++;
  iterable_for_result++;
  console.log(num_display);
});

// operator click event listener

op.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(operatorType);
    if (clicked > 1) {
      clicked -= 2;
      count++;
      clear();
    } else if (clicked <= 1) {
      count++;
      decimal.disabled = false;
      decimalClicks = 0;
      clicked++;
      clear();
    }
  })
});

//Stores the operator clicked into operator object
function operatorTypeFunction(operator) {
  operatorSequence++;
  operatorStorage[`Operator ${operatorSequence}`] = operator;
  operatorType = operatorStorage[`Operator ${operatorSequence}`];
  console.log(operatorStorage);
}
// clears only the inputted value
function clear() {
  input.value = "";
}

function add(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}

function subtract(num1, num2) {
  return num1 - num2;
}

function multiply(num1, num2) {
  return num1 * num2;
}

function divide(num1, num2) {
  return num1 / num2;
}

// second inputted value
function storedKeys(i) {
  return num_display[Object.keys(num_display)[i]];
}

// first inputted value/ also stored as the final result of every operation performed
// i.e. firstvalue = 10; secondvalue = 12;
// newvalue = firstvalue + secondvalue;
// Make firstvalue = 0 and then... 
// firstvalue += newvalue

function resultNum1(i) {
  if (operationResult == 0 && Object.keys(num_display).length <= 2) {
    console.log('result ' + num_display[Object.keys(num_display)[i]]);
    return num_display[Object.keys(num_display)[i]];
  } else {
    if (isNaN(operationResult) == true) {
      operationResult = 0;
      return operationResult;
    } else {
      return num_display['result'];
    }
  }
}



function evaluateOperation(iterable_variable_1, iterable_variable_2) {
  let postResultIterable = 0;
  let resultNumIterable = -1;
  if (Object.keys(num_display).length > 2) {
    console.log('Run');
    // Something wrong with iteration, it loops through everything when all numbers are calculated
    // it does another full loop with the new calculation after exiting the loop
    for (let i = 1; i <= Object.keys(operatorStorage).length; i++) {
      // The logging are to help to see the result and what is being used in the operate func
      console.log(i);
      resultNumIterable++;
      postResultIterable++;
      console.log(operatorStorage[`Operator ${i}`]);
      console.log(storedKeys(postResultIterable));
      operationResult = operate(operatorStorage[`Operator ${i}`], resultNum1(resultNumIterable), storedKeys(postResultIterable));
      num_display['result'] = 0;
      num_display['result'] += operationResult;
    }
    return num_display['result'];
  } else {
    return operate(operatorType, resultNum1(iterable_variable_1), storedKeys(iterable_variable_2));
  }
}
//Clears all data stored and the input

clearAllData.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let key in num_display) {
    for (let i = count; i >= 0; i--) {
      num_display['result'] = 0;
      delete num_display[`post_op_result ${i}`];
      delete operatorStorage[`Operator ${i}`];
    }
  }
  clear();
  operationResult = 0;
  count = 0;
  clicked = 1;
  decimalClicks = 0;
  iterable_for_post_result = 1;
  iterable_for_result = 0;
  operatorSequence = 0;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80vh;
}

.grid_buttons {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#calc_display {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#calc_display:hover {
  outline: none;
}

.equal {
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

.grid_buttons div>* {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(53, 157, 223);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.equal button {
  background-color: rgb(53, 157, 223);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_buttons">
  <input type="text" id="calc_display" value="" readonly>
  <div id="decimal"><button class="number">.</button></div>
  <div><button class="operator" id="multiply" onclick="operatorTypeFunction('*');">*</button></div>
  <div><button class="operator" id="divide" onclick="operatorTypeFunction('/')">/</button></div>
  <div><button class="operator" id="add" onclick="operatorTypeFunction('+')">+</button></div>
  <div><button class="operator" id="subtract" onclick="operatorTypeFunction('-')">-</button></div>
  <div class="clear"><button>AC</button></div>
  <div id="7"><button class="number">7</button></div>
  <div id="8"><button class="number">8</button></div>
  <div id="9"><button class="number">9</button></div>
  <div id="4"><button class="number">4</button></div>
  <div id="5"><button class="number">5</button></div>
  <div id="6"><button class="number">6</button></div>
  <div id="1"><button class="number">1</button></div>
  <div id="2"><button class="number">2</button></div>
  <div id="3"><button class="number">3</button></div>
  <div id="0"><button class="number">0</button></div>
  <div class="equal"><button id="evaluate">=</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Muaad, at first glance this looks like a debugging question that Stackoverflow is not really designed for, can you reproduce the problem with a minimal example? See: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to make a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: just use a break statement to stop the loop?

Comment: The thing is it exits the loop completely and returns the result, and then it goes back to the start of the loop, this time with the updated result.

Answer (score 0):

It's not looping twice, you're calling `evaluateOperation()` twice. First in

```
let errorMessage = evaluateOperation(iterable_for_result, iterable_for_post_result);
```

and again in

```
input.value = `${evaluateOperation(iterable_for_result, iterable_for_post_result)}`;
```

Instead of calling it again, just use the value you assigned from the first call:

```
input.value = error_message;
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that out recently, probably wouldn't have realised that if that though hadn't occurred to me. How was my commenting ? Was it easy to read ?

Comment: The comments are pretty good. They explain the logic, rather than just saying what the code does.